# Retrieving data from online DB

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I've got a simple database out on my GoDaddy account and I'm trying to retrieve data from it. I've set up a simple php file out on my account and can call it directly from a browser and it shows the retrieved data just fine. You can see it/run it here:

```
http://thunderbirdtechnology.com/SnapVest/php/SnapVestDatabaseRetrieveAvailableOptions.php
```

You'll get the following displayed:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "CompanyName": "Yahoo Inc.",
        "DateInvestStart": "2014-02-19 14:35:56",
        "DateInvestEnd": "2014-02-28 11:35:44",
        "DatePurchase": "2014-03-11 11:35:51"
    }
]
```

All well and good.

But then I'm trying to do that from my JAVA program running on my ANDROID phone. And it doesn't work. Here's the section of code:

```
        InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Here is where we specify where our php file (see sample above) is that will do the actual
        // gathering up of the data.
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.ThunderbirdTechnology.com/SnapVes/php/SnapVestDatabaseRetrieveAvailableOptions.php");
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity();

        inputStream = httpentity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // Report "Error in http connect to database"
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Error in http connect to database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try
        {
            // Convert response to string
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }

            inputStream.close();
            result = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Report "Error converting result"
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Error converting result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

It does indeed retrieve some data. But here's the WEIRD PART! It's NOT retrieving my data from my database table. Instead, it's retrieving some ODD FILE from I-don't-know-where!

HERE'S A SAMPLE OF WHAT IT'S RETRIEVING:

```
<!--
   Copyright 2003, CyberTAN  Inc.  All Rights Reserved
This is SOURCE CODE of CyberTAN Inc.
the contents of this file may not be disclosed to third parties,
copied or duplicated in any form without the prior written
permission of CyberTAN Inc.
This software should be used as a reference only, and it not
intended for production use!
THIS SOFTWARE IS OFFERED "AS IS", AND CYBERTAN GRANTS NO WARRANTIES OF ANY
KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, BY STATUTE, COMMUNICATION OR OTHERWISE.  CYBERTAN
SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIMS ANY IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS
FOR A SPECIFIC PURPOSE OR NONINFRINGEMENT CONCERNING THIS SOFTWARE
-->
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE></TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

What the heck is THAT? I have no clue who/what CyberTan is. Why am I not getting the data from my database? It seems to be connecting to it OK. It seems to be executing the php file OK, but what it actually returns is from some file I've never seen.

I'm totally confused. :)

Comment: Have you tried a different endpoint with your Javacode that is also JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you are not getting firewall or packet inspection issues while on your mobile?  CyberTan seems to make wifi / router products.  I would check your home router for wireless and see if there is some protection thing blocking you.  Similar to how some email servers will read your attachments and look for code.

Also if you are seeing in your access logs that the webserver is being hit, then you are interested in the response coming back.  Some good old tcpdump / wireshark will get you that info since its not over HTTPS

Comment: Here's an interesting difference. I just connected via a different WiFi network and I do indeed get a code 200 and OK response (as with the other WiFi network) but the data that comes back is actually an html page prompting me for a password login for the network.

So, it does seem that something is getting in the way of my actually connecting through to my php file.

I DO have a local WiFi network for my computers but each time I try to connect through MY WiFi network it indicates connection failure. That's why I was defaulting to some other local (apparently free access) WiFi network.

Comment: Yes, it was a firewall problem. When I was finally able to get connected through my own local WiFi I was no longer getting those weird files but instead am now getting the actual data from my database.

THANK YOU  (or "Mahalo" as we say here in Hawaii) for all your help.

Comment: no problem, i have had my fair share of intercepting equipment, virus scanners, and other riff raff.  glad you didnt have to spend days and then beat your router into a pulp when you discovered it.  haha. :)

Answer (score 1):

Quick Google search tells me that [CyberTAN Inc.](http://www.cybertan.com.tw/company/overview.htm) is a manufacturer of networking / wireless equipment. So what you are seeing there is probably the response of your WLAN router.

And what you are seeing is also probably some kind of odd (cached) response to a 404 error. There is a tiny typo in your hard-coded URL in your Java POST request:

```
http://www.ThunderbirdTechnology.com/SnapVes/php/SnapVestDatabaseRetrieveAvailableOptions.php
                                           ^ -- t missing
```

You should definitely read the response status code and check if it's not an error that should be handled somehow. You probably could have seen, that it is a 404. Furthermore you should be more specific with your catch-all-exceptions block that executes the POST request. Only catch what is explicitly thrown by these methods and log the actual exception.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for finding that typo.
I examined the returned Status and it comes back "OK" code = 200, which supposedly means that it performed the operation just fine.
Yet it's still getting that file content instead of the database data.

Comment: @RogerGarrett Hm... your router is funny. Maybe it cannot resolve the domain name written in camel-case notation. Try writing it in all lower-case. You could also try your Android device's cell phone network data connection instead of WLAN, if available. Maybe resetting the router helps, or better try accessing its admin page and look for some caching related features you could clear or switch off

Comment: Your pointing out that I had a typo in my URL prompted me to look closely at some other potential typos. Since my eyes are getting older (along with the r est of me), it turned out that I was having trouble reading the tiny lettering of the password on bottom of my Belkin WiFi router, and I had repeatedly put in the wrong password when trying to connect to my own network. Now that I have  the right password, everything's working just fine.

Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.